# Recruiter keeps messing up offer letter

Tags: recruitment, human-resources, offer

I got an offer but the recruiter keeps making mistakes on the offer letter. I have asked her to fix it twice and somehow she adds an end date that shouldn't exist.

I have reached out to her last Friday, but she hasn't gotten back to me yet. Should I wait for her response? If not, should I call her or email her?

At this point I want to push back the start date too since the offer letter got delayed by a whole week at this point.

Comment: Call her ASAP, and leave a message on her voice mail. Then, send a her an email to remind her also. It is her job to be the fast and efficient lane of communication between you and the company.

Comment: May be worth mentioning if the recruiter is part of the company or independent.

Comment: She is part of the company

Comment: Never ever wait for something this critical. You call, email, and visit in person if you want it. If you've talked to non-hiring members of the company, you follow up with them to let them know that things are not happening and get them to advocate for you internally.

Comment: "somehow she adds an end date that shouldn't exist" An end date to the **offer** or to the **job** they want to hire you for? Those are two very different things. It's not unusual for job offers to be time-limited for legal reasons. But if your permanent position was just turned into a fixed length contract that's very different.

Answer (score 4):

At this point of the process, it seems unlikely that the company would withdraw its offer. Your question seems to hint that your future employer would like you to start pretty quickly. Maybe in a week or two? I suspect that, given the situation (starting soon and the recruiter taking more than two business days to get back to you), not being satisfied with the offer would justify postponing the start date. However, if the start date you mentioned is sufficiently far away in the future, I would advise you to be more sympathetic to the recruiter and not necessarily ask to push it back.

Revising the offer by adding an end date looks pretty unprofessional, in my opinion. It should have been there in the first place if they wanted to put a time limit on the offer. At this point, alterations to the offer should be negotiated between the two parties, not hastily added by the recruiter alone. I wouldn't necessarily deem it a red flag but, if I were you, I would be suspicious about the professionalism of your future employer.

Another element that would be important to take into consideration is the importance of the changes you requested about the offer. Since you're talking about mistakes and fixes, it looks like they might be minor issues like typos. I wouldn't be too worried about them even if, once again, it seems unprofessional. If the issues are more severe, like an error about your compensation or your responsibilities, then I would take it more seriously and would make sure that the offer is completely satisfactory before accepting it.

Comment: Also, performing substantive changes to a contract without notification can be seen as acting in bad faith (a legal term), this is in addition to being unprofessional as you indicate.

Answer (score 2):

This is a red flag. While it may not be a "run for the hills" situation, the fact that their internal HR seems unable to provide an offer letter that matches what you presumably interviewed for shows either malice or incompetence. More than likely, this individual is just incompetent.

Working for a company who's HR department has this level of ineptitude is always a gamble. There is always the opportunity for them to screw something up that screws you over (such as work authorizations if you travel for work to other countries, or tax withholding if your W4 is improperly entered in their system) but likely doesn't reflect the actual work culture at the company.

In the less likely scenario that it is due to malice, or acting in bad faith, you won't find out until you accept and begin working for them, in which case your options are to quit or bear with.

Given that it's an internal recruiter, I personally wouldn't risk it. On the other hand, I have just recently (< 2 weeks ago) risked it when an external recruiter had the same issues. In that case, I contacted my future employer and let them know of a potential delay in my start due to paperwork problems. It was resolved less than 24H from that point. To reiterate, I would have withdrawn my application if it had been an internal recruiter, since it's that big of a red flag.